# ListView notify Column drag

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to be notified when column drag-n-drop operation is ended to update "column order".
I have found that [LVN_COLUMNDROPDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774806%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is suported from Windows Vista.
What is the WinXp way of doing that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. [HDN_ENDDRAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775269%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
Sorry for noise :)